# Convert dictionary with tuples as keys to tuples that contain keys and value

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary like this:

```
d = {('a','b','c'):4, ('e','f','g'):6}
```

and I would like to have a set of tuples like this:

```
{('a', 'b', 'c', 4), ('e', 'f', 'g', 6)}
```

I've tried in this way:

```
b = set(zip(d.keys(), d.values()))
```

But the output is this:

```
set([(('a', 'b', 'c'), 4), (('e', 'f', 'g'), 6)])
```

How can i solve that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to zip the keys with the values, you want to concatenate them:

```
>>> {k + (v,) for k, v in d.items()}
{('a', 'b', 'c', 4), ('e', 'f', 'g', 6)}
```

Answer (score 6):

In Python >= 3.5, you can use [generalized unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-448-additional-unpacking-generalizations) in this [set comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
{(*k, v) for k, v in d.items()}
# {('a', 'b', 'c', 4), ('e', 'f', 'g', 6)}
```

But the more universally applicable `tuple` concatenation approach as [suggested by Aran-Fey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52964027/convert-dictionary-with-tuples-as-keys-to-tuples-that-contain-keys-and-value/#answer-52964061) is not significantly more verbose:

```
{k + (v,) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a set comprehension to iterate over the key, value pairs, and then create new tuples from the exploded (unpacked) key and the value:

```
>>> {(*k, v) for k, v in d.items()}
{('e', 'f', 'g', 6), ('a', 'b', 'c', 4)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try `map`:

```
print(set(map(lambda k: k[0]+(k[1],),d.items())))
```

Or (python 3.5 up):

```
print(set(map(lambda k: (*k[0],k[1]),d.items())))
```